# Get model download statistics for TFhub

Tags: tensorflow-hub

I'm working on a tool for [TF hub models](https://tfhub.dev) and would like to test it on a representative sample of models.  Is there a way do programmatically download a full list of TF hub models along with their download numbers (to judge popularity) other than scraping the website?

Also, I've noticed that the download numbers for some models (Ex: https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/efficientnet/lite0/classification/2) are missing, and on a day-to-day basis, the download numbers sometimes go down.  Is there any explanation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to download all models or model stats. The bug regarding the decreasing download counts should be fixed by now.